# Is probability distribution known in parametric inference?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, fisher-information

I have two questions about *parametric inference*. Assume we estimate parameter $\theta$ from a set of measurements.

1. Is probability distribution $p(x|\theta)$ known from the begining? In other words, do we know the probability distribution function and its dependence on $\theta$? I think without this information it would be impossible to calculate e.q. Fisher Information and decide if the estimator is biased or unbiased.
2. Imagine the following situation. We assumed some $p(x|\theta)$ and calculated Fisher information $\mathcal{I}(\theta)$ and constructed unbiased estimator $\hat{\theta}$. This gave us some prediction about the uncertainity of the estimator $\Delta \hat{\theta} \geq 1/\sqrt{\mathcal{I}(\theta)}$. What happens when during the measurements it turned out we assumed wrong $p(x|\theta)$? How will it influence uncertanity of the estimator $\Delta \hat{\theta}$?

Comment: You should look at the topic of [mis-specified models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_(regression)) to see the considerable amount of work available on these questions. The properties of estimators will hugely vary depending on the degree of misspecification.

Comment: It would be difficult to make any sense of $\theta$ in (1) unless the answer were yes!